# Widget build method returning error - This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to find out what is wrong with the below code for sometime. It says **This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement.**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
        initialData: false,
        future: Authentication().fetchAuthSession(),
        builder: (context, future) {
          switch (future.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting :
              {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            case ConnectionState.done :
              {
                if (future.data == false) {
                  print('Done');  
                } else print('Not Done');
                break;
              }
          }
        }
    );
  }
```

EDIT - after applying the items mentioned in the answer. I am still getting the same error

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
        initialData: false,
        future: Authentication().fetchAuthSession(),
        builder: (context, future) {
          switch (future.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting :
              {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            case ConnectionState.done :
              {
                if (future.data == false) {
                  print('Done');
                } else {
                  print('Not Done');
                  return Container();
                }
              }
            default :
              {
                return Container();
              }
          }
        }
    );
  }
```

Comment: The `builder` in `FutureBuilder` should return a `Widget`. In your code, it returns a `Widget` only when connection is waiting. It does not return a widget when the data is retrieved. Try returning a widget below the `switch (...) {...} <insert return widget here>`.

Comment: Thanks @rickimaru, could you please check my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the error message, since the `builder` expect a Widget to be returned, your `switch`/ `case` block needs to return a Widget on every case. Use the `default` keyword as well in case no condition is met. You can do this:

```dart
builder: (context, future) {
  switch (future.connectionState) { 
    case ConnectionState.done:  // The bracelet is not needed for case
        if (future.data == false) {
          print('Done');
        } else {
          print('Not Done');
        }
        return Container(); // return a Widget here, for example Container()
    case ConnectionState.waiting:
    default:     
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
```

[image]

The code is cleaner though if you use simple if/ else statement with `hasData`:

```dart
builder: (context, future) {
  if (!future.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
  if (future.data) {
    print('Done');
  } else {
    print('Not Done');
  }
  return Container(); // return a Widget here, for example Container()
}
```

[image]

Comment: I copied your code with the if statement, still I am getting the same error

Comment: @Sumchans The code you updated your question with doesn't return a Widget within the `if (future.data == false)` which cause the error. Btw you don't need to use bracelet for `case`.  I've updated my answer with the picture using the 2 of my code blocks, no error should come up

Answer (score 2):

**Two things** you have to consider here so that inside the builder, the code makes sure some widget is returned on every block.

**First**
Make a default case inside your switch statement.

```
  switch (future.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
      {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      default:
      {
        return Container();
      }
  }
```

**Second** instead of breaking, return with some Widget inside all cases.

```
case ConnectionState.done:
  {
    if (future.data == false) {
      print('Done');
    } else
      print('Not Done');
    return Container();   // Just an empty container widget for example
  }
default:
 {
   return Container();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul. I am still getting the same error, I have modified my original post with your answer. please check.